# C++ Template partial class specialization with function specialisation

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to do something that appears simple using templates but I just cannot get it working. The class is implementing various serial IO implementations for an AVR processor but the issue is a generic C++ issue. The goal is to make options at compile time based on template parameters for user-friendliness and increased code reuse along with better performance in some places due to that reuse.

The issue is simple but a solution (if any) I cannot find. When compiling the code that follows using Visual Studio 2008 I get:

```
error C2039: 't1' : is not a member of 'Interface<T1,0,_C>
error C2039: 't1' : is not a member of 'Interface<T1,1,_C>
error C2039: 't2' : is not a member of 'Interface<T2,0,_C>
error C2039: 't2' : is not a member of 'Interface<T2,1,_C>
```

** I have split my test code up into explanatory chunks, put them all together for the whole test case **

This is the 'generic' base template:

```
enum eType { T1,  T2 };
enum eT1  { T1_I1, T1_I2 };
enum eT2  { T2_I1, T2_I2 };

//This defines the 'global/default' interface that is required
template< eType _T, int _I, typename _C>
struct Interface
{
    bool initialise();
};
```

For this I partially specialise the template based on the _T parameter to add member variables that are used by initialise() etc:

```
//t1 has a new member function which initialise() uses
template< int _I, typename _C>
struct Interface< T1, _I, _C >
{
    bool initialise();
    void t1();
};

//t2 has a new member function which initialise() might uses
template< int _I, typename _C>
struct Interface< T2, _I, _C >
{
    bool initialise();
    void t2();
};

//We can implement a function for T1 type
template< int _I, typename _C>
bool Interface< T1, _I, _C >::initialise()
{ printf( "T1 initialise\n"); return true; }

//We can implement a function for T2 type
template< int _I, typename _C>
bool Interface< T2, _I, _C >::initialise()
{ printf( "T2 initialise\n"); return true; }

//We can implement a function for T1 special function
template< int _I, typename _C>
void Interface< T1, _I, _C >::t1()
{ printf( "T1\n"); }

//We can implement a function for T2 special function
template< int _I, typename _C>
void Interface< T2, _I, _C >::t2()
{ printf( "T2\n"); }
```

Now to the bit that I cannot work out how to accoumplish where I want to specialise the implementation of the t1() and t2() functions based on the second template parameter _I.

```
//################ ISUE BELOW ###################

//ERROR: We can't implement the special function for T1 based on _I specialization
template< typename _C>
void Interface< T1, (int)T1_I1, _C >::t1()
{ printf( "T1_I1 Special function\n"); }

//ERROR: We can't implement the special function for T1 based on _I specialization
template< typename _C>
void Interface< T1, (int)T1_I2, _C >::t1()
{ printf( "T1_I2 Special function\n"); }

//ERROR: We can't implement the special function for T2 based on _I specialization
template< typename _C>
void Interface< T2, (int)T2_I1, _C >::t2()
{ printf( "T2_I1 Special function\n"); }

//ERROR: We can't implement the special function for T2 based on _I specialization
template< typename _C>
void Interface< T2, (int)T2_I2, _C >::t2()
{ printf( "T2_I2 Special function\n"); }

//################ ISUE END ###################
```

Now to the main() function which  tests it all compiles:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct Config {};
    Interface<T1, T1_I1, Config> t1i1;
    Interface<T1, T1_I2, Config> t1i2;
    Interface<T2, T2_I1, Config> t2i1;
    Interface<T2, T2_I2, Config> t2i2;

    t1i1.initialise();
    t1i2.initialise();
    t1i1.t1();
    t1i2.t1();

    t2i1.initialise();
    t2i2.initialise();
    t2i1.t2();
    t2i2.t2();
    return 0;
}
```

The issue appears to be caused by the compiler not seeing the existence of the original class specialization and it is using the non specialized interface which does not have a t1() or t2(). Where have I got the syntax wrong here or is there a simple hack/work around to accomplish what I am trying to do. As long as a solution can result in a type in the form of `Serial<UART,Hardware,Config> io` it meets my goal!

Comment: You cannot do that. Function templates cannot be specialized partially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to spell out all the partial *class* specializations one by one. Example:

```
template <eType E, int I, typename T> struct Interface;

template <int I, typename T> struct Interface<T1, I, T>
{ 
    void t1() { /* ... */ }
    bool initialize() { /* ... */ }
};

template <typename T> struct Interface<T1, static_cast<int>(T1), T>
{ 
    void t1() { /* ... */ }
    bool initialize() { /* ... */ }
};
```

You could always factor your code to avoid repetition when appropriate. For example:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, int I> struct T1Helper
    {
        static bool initialize() { /* ... */ }
    };
}

// ... primary template as above ...

template <int I, typename T> struct Interface<T1, I, T>
{
     void t1() { /* ... */ }
     bool initialize() { return detail::T1Helper<T, I>::initialize(); }
};

// etc.
```

Or you could factor the common code into a mixin template:

```
template <int I, typename T>
struct Interface<T1, I, T> : Mixin<T, I>
{
    void t1() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. I see that there is no way to get partial function specialization and your three examples are very useful in showing how to work around this. I will be trying a version of the MixIn where it is a Helper which hopefulyl will have all the features I need. Thanks again for your help.